# How to set Content-Type correctly?

Tags: java, http

I want to change Content-Type but it dose not work...right?
code:

```
  HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

  System.out.println(conn.getContentType());
```

the output is not  "text/plain; charset=utf-8"...anything wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `conn`? Are you trying to change the `Content-Type` output to the browser from within a JSP?

Comment: oh...sorry,i will edit...wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of [`getContentType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) returns the value of the `Content-Type` header from the response, not the value set on the request. See the Javadoc I linked to. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to post a url..i use "conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");" to set the html content-type from servers ...did i make a mistake?

Comment: That sets the `Content-Type` of the request you are sending. You cannot directly control the `Content-Type` of the server response unless the resource at that URL provides some mechanism to allow you to.

Answer (score 3):

As laz correctly points out, setting `Content-Type` on the outgoing request isn't going to control the `Content-Type` you are going to get back on the response.  If you have a server which is smart enough to dynamically control the `Content-Type` the correct way to request a specific one is via an [Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.
>    The example
>
> ```
>   Accept: audio/*; q=0.2, audio/basic
> ```
>
> SHOULD be interpreted as "I prefer audio/basic, but send me any audio type if it is the best available after an 80% mark-down in quality."

Comment: Note that most services you might talk to over HTTP probably will not support this unless they specifically claim to.  You have to design your service to support it (or use a framework which does).